# Can I access local file in Pig?

Tags: file, apache-pig

I have a file named blacklist.xml, each line of this file contains a absolute path, multiple path is in this file. This file is store at /Users/ABC/

May I know if there is anyway that I can load this file from the local directory (/Users/ABC/) but not from HDFS? Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run Pig in local mode using the command line option `-x local`.  Pig only works with a single filesystem at once -- if you wish to use a hadoop instance, storing temporary and output data to HDFS, then all of your input files will also need to be on HDFS.

An exception is if you are using the local file as a collection of parameters, in which case you should look up how to read parameters from file.